# pre-receive hook declined while trying to push GHOST

Tags: heroku, ghost-blog

I'm trying to host ghost blog to via heroku app. While trying to push using command 'git push heroku main' and I'm getting following error:

```
Enumerating objects: 117255, done.
Counting objects: 100% (117255/117255), done.
Delta compression using up to 12 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (36381/36381), done.
Writing objects: 100% (117255/117255), 50.31 MiB | 1.39 MiB/s, done.
Total 117255 (delta 78401), reused 117229 (delta 78377), pack-reused 0
remote: Git submodules detected, installing:
remote: Submodule 'content/themes/casper' (/mnt/endosome/workspaces/TryGhost/Casper.git) 
registered for path 'content/themes/casper'
remote: Submodule 'core/client' (/mnt/endosome/workspaces/TryGhost/Admin.git) registered for 
path 'core/client'
remote: fatal: repository '/mnt/endosome/workspaces/TryGhost/Casper.git' does not exist
remote: fatal: clone of '/mnt/endosome/workspaces/TryGhost/Casper.git' into submodule path 
'content/themes/casper' failed
remote: 
remote: !       Push rejected, submodule install failed
```

I referred to https://github.com/TryGhost/Ghost/issues/10265, but the fixes mentioned aren't working for me either.

Answer (score 0):

You should ask whoever maintains the repo at git@mycogit/cit_pplus.git.

Your commits were rejected by the pre-receive hook of that repo (that's a user-configurable script that is intended to analyze incoming commits and decide if they are good enough to be accepted into the repo).

It is also a good idea to ask that person to update the hook, so it would print the reasons for the rejection.

If the maintainer is you yourself, then it looks like you've got a problem with your setup on the server-side. Please share more information then.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. This repo is created as a part of a new application via Heroku CLI - "heroku create". I have not explicitly added any pre-receive hooks. Any ideas on how can get more info on the failures via heroku?

Comment: @utkarshsharma Can you check the heroku logs and see if they provide any clues?

Comment: @utkarshsharma https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars